# android java.lang.string cannot be converted to jsonarray

Tags: java, android, json, string, exception

I've been searching through the Internet for a while, still have no idea what should I do... here's my code:

```
String res = "...";
        JSONArray jArr = new JSONArray(res);
```

res contains following:

```
[["000000000001","club1","www.example.com","some adress"],["000000000002","club2","www.example.com","some adress2"]]
```

I just keep getting this error and don't know how to fix it, please help :C

Comment: please give error details.

Comment: [Dublicated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11743422/string-cannot-be-converted-to-jsonarray)

Answer (score 0):

I tried your code and its working fine. Here is the code I tried :

```
String res = "[[\"000000000001\",\"club1\",\"www.example.com\",\"some adress\"],[\"000000000002\",\"club2\",\"www.example.com\",\"some adress2\"]]";
        try {
             jArr = new JSONArray(res);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.e("Array", "" + jArr.toString());
```

and here is the output :

```
[["000000000001","club1","www.example.com","some adress"],["000000000002","club2","www.example.com","some adress2"]]
```